# Ruby: Declarative_authorization polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations, declarative-authorization

I have two models (Item and Theme).  They are both owned by a third model Users with a has_many association (User has many Themes and Items). Both Item and Theme have_many :images.

The Image model is a polymorphic association so the table has the columns imageable_id and imageable_type.  If I had both an Item with ID 1 and a Theme with ID 1 the table would look like

```
id    imageable_id    imageable_type
------------------------------------
1     1               Item
2     1               Theme
```

I'm using declarative_authorization to re-write the SQL queries of my database to keep users from accessing items outside their account.  I'd like to write an authorization rule that will allow a user to read an image only if they can read the item they own.  I can't seem to get the correct syntax (perhaps it's not supported):

```
has_permission_on [:images], :to => [:manage], :join_as => :and do
  if_attribute :imageable => is { "Item" }
  if_permitted_to :manage, :items # Somehow I need to tell declarative_auth to imageable_id is an item_id in this case.
end
```

Then I'd have another rule mimicking the above but for themes:

```
has_permission_on [:images], :to => [:manage], :join_as => :and do
  if_attribute :imageable => is { "Theme" }
  if_permitted_to :manage, :themes # Somehow I need to tell declarative_auth to imageable_id is a theme_id in this case.
end
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

- Corith Malin

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you commit a mistake in **`has_permission_on`** method

As I checked over [has_permission_on](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization/blob/45e91af20eba71b2828c5c84066bcce3ef032e8a/lib/declarative_authorization/reader.rb#L277) and [if_attribute](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization/blob/45e91af20eba71b2828c5c84066bcce3ef032e8a/lib/declarative_authorization/reader.rb#L397)

```
  has_permission_on(:images, :to => :manage, :join_as => :and) do
    if_attribute :imageable => "Item"
    if_permitted_to :manage, :items
  end
```

Hope this Help You !!!